# How to deal with employer giving tasks completely out of scope?

Tags: professionalism, management, company-policy

I started working at a small IT company as a tech a week ago. Most of my job consist of computer repair, configuration, and as well as customer support.

The other day I received a document from the hiring manager that I will also be in charge of keeping the men's restroom clean (taking out the trash), and dusting off the work vans that we use. I really didn't mind this until the other tech who has been working here for a year told me he didn't do that when he started.

I know that they can afford a janitor because of how much their senior staff gets paid. My job is an entry level one but I have some previous experience and also had other interviews on the side but chose this one when offered to me.To my current knowledge no other new employees have had to do this.

**How can I deal with my employer giving me tasks that I didn't sign up for, and are not even related to my position whatsoever?**

Answer (score 19):

Quit? No

Complain? Of course

Highlight to your boss that you were not aware that this would be part of the job. Point out that you took the job on good faith and that if they had wanted a janitor they should have advertised as such. Explain that you feel it unfair and propose a rota, or other system that is fairer.

Comment: So in the event that he does not care what else should I do? I don't even want to attempt to take the trash out.

Comment: @Bex It's no use asking us to follow up on all hypothetical answers from your boss. One step at a time, please.